# Creating an LVM group

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm, parted

I have rented a dedicated server with two 500gb hardisks running centos 6.

On this server there are 3 partitions.

1. boot
2. root 50gb
3. swap 50gb
4. empty 400gb

Now I want to create a logical volume group spanning the empty 400gb on the first disk and merginging it with the empty 400gb on the second disk.

I've read tutorial after tutorial but I cannot understand how to accomplish this task. I just want to merge the empty partition with the empty disk.

Can someone please suggest how may I accomplish this, or if it is at all possible?

Comment: Please avoid from asking your question in multiple forums. Your question was also answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258174/how-to-properly-use-lvm

Comment: I recommend you use mirroring instead of spanning. Who knows what kind of crappy drivers are in that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this.  There are 3 parts to LVM -

- The Physical Volume
- The Volume Group
- Logical Volumes

So the way I would do this is to create a partition on the second disk (you don't *need* to do this, but its the "correct" way to do it)

First instruct the Operating system that you have 2 Physical Volumes you wish to assign to LVM - you do this by running the following command for each of the 2 partitions

```
pvcreate /dev/sdXX
```

The second step is to assign both physical volumes into 1 volume group -

```
vgcreate vgname /dev/sdXX /dev/sdXX
```

The third step is to create a logical volume

```
lvcreate -n NewPartitionName vg -L 899G
```

In this example I've created an 899 gig block device which will be called /dev/vgname/NewPartitionName.   Depending on your needs, seriously consider starting off only using, say 800 Gigs of space, leaving the last 99 gigs free - this will give you freedom to create additional volumes - including snapshots, which can be useful.  You can always expand the current volume later (even when the filesystem is in use).  Its is easier to make a volume bigger then smaller.

At this stage you are ready to add your filesystem.  Not sure if you need help here, but you could use a command mkfs.ext4 /dev/vgname/NewPartitionName  to format the partition.   You can then add it to your fstab file if you want it to be automatically mounted.